# How to do predict() for linearmodels

Tags: python, panel-data, linearmodels

Below is Fixed Effect Estimation python code by linearmodels module from [here](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/models.html#linearmodels.panel.model.PanelOLS).

`from linearmodels import PanelOLS
mod = PanelOLS(y_train, x_train, entity_effects=True)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)`

How can we do `predict(x_test)` operation as `sklearn` after `mod.fit()` ?

Comment: try `res.predict(x_test)`

Comment: Thanks @skrubber. There is no `predict()` function for `res` object.

Comment: oh yeah predict was defined for statsmodels. Spotchecked examples from [here](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/tree/master/examples) and looks like a predict function doesn't exist. For your use case, if you choose linearmodels, I think you have to forego predict. Also, why do you want to use linearmodels and then predict with sklearn, when you know that the regression models and sensitivity is totally different for both?

Comment: I need the `fixed effect model`, `random effect model` and `mixed effect model` at linearmodels. You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645480/what-is-best-python-module-for-panel-data-regressionfixed-effect-model-random) for more details about my case.

Answer (score 1):

Conformed with the author that `linearmodels` still not support the function `predict()`, the development of this feature is in progress. Refer to [here](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/issues/130) for more details.